# Is there a way to make Blueprint CSS grid fluid?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

Is there any tool to recalculate px values in % ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Christian Montoya's plugin [liquidgrid](http://github.com/Montoya/blueprint-plugin---liquidgrid/)